# Why Google Compute Engine Removing user app?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, phantomjs, google-compute-engine

I have run nodejs app on Google Compute Engine. The app is using a [phantom-works](https://github.com/pofider/phantom-workers) witch starts few phantom process (one process - listening on one port). After few houers app responses on requests (on this ports) I got logs like:

```
... instance-1 google-accounts: INFO Removing user app.
```

What is the reason of deleting app process port? 
Are processes having deleted by Google Compute Engine or phantom-workers app?

Comment: The options offered by phantom-workers include timeout. Have you set this timeout as indicated in the documentation: "timeout - execution timeout in ms", or accepted a default? This may explain the processes being stopped after a while.

Comment: @George Yes, I have set this phantom-workers timeout. But, no matter if I set 25000 ms or 250000 ms the process being stopped after a while. It seeems to be removeing process by google compute engine daemon, not by phantom-workers, becouse in log we have "instance-1 google-accounts:", or am I wrong?

Comment: If you set the timeout parameter, your processes will get stopped after the set delay. What happens if you don't set this parameter? Will your processes get then stopped by the compute engine?

Comment: @George Yes, processes get stopped.

Comment: To properly investigate and reproduce this issue, there is a need to have access to a copy of your node.js code in view of local testing and deployment. This is much easier in the [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35901849). You are encouraged to open an issue there. Communication will be then set to private, to protect sensitive details.